# Browser response Timeout

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am doing a Perl CGI scripting on HTML  . In my Perl script i have used send expect statements and print statements  . I have used $exp->log_user(0) do that the browser will not display those send expect results. When i run my script in Browser only, the print statements are printed and i get some results. This runs for around 5 min. however when i comment out the print statements, the browser is not displaying the final result. Is it that, since the browser is not getting the response of print statement, it timed out?

Please help

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain that the browser will give up before 5 minutes is completed.

What you would normally do for something like this is:

1. Have a separate "expect job runner" process.
2. Add jobs to a queue so it can run them.
3. Show the user a "processing, please wait" page which auto-reloads (javascript or meta refresh). When the job is complete it can display the output instead.

You need a way for the job runner and the web-page code to communicate - usually a shared database or queue system.

Step 3 might be handled by AJAX requests nowadays but the overall structure is the same.

Two things to consider in your design:

1. Handling errors from the job runner
2. Preventing users from repeatedly submitting the same job because they get impatient and think it's not working.